I can't get discussion between Jack Reacher and hairdresser
That's a discussion:

Reacher said, “Five bucks? I remember when five bucks got you two hamburgers and the back row of the movies. Plus car fare for her, if you fell out along the way. A shave and a haircut was two bits.” “Was that an homage?” “What?” “Did you say that deliberately?” “Sometimes I let things out by accident, but generally only one syllable at a time.” “Therefore you said it deliberately. It was an homage. You were building the energy.

My first two questions are:

Why it was homage. As I understand, homage is showing respect, but I can't see it from Reacher's words
What does it mean "building the energy"?


[I don't get the discussion etc.]

Please provide a link so we can hear it.

It's from book, not from movie
